# UiCollectionView - why my textlabel value not updating?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

my LBLLikesDetail.text is not updating

```
func api_addQuoteToFavourite(){
    let data = ["user_id":UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constant.UserDefault.user_app_id)!,"quote_id":STRQuoteId] as NSDictionary
    MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    Webservices_Alamofier.postWithURL(serverlink: Constant.GlobalDeclare.Mainlink, methodname: Constant.GlobalDeclare.addQuoteToFavourite, param: data, key: "") { (Success, Responce) in
         MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.view, animated: true)
        if Success == true{

            let cell = self.CollecDetail.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: self.mypath) as! CollectionViewCell


            if let data = Responce.object(forKey: "data") as? NSDictionary {
                if let counts = data.object(forKey: "quote_favourite_count"){
                    cell.LBLLikesDetail.text! =  String("\(counts)")
                    print(cell.LBLLikesDetail.text!)
                    self.CollecDetail.reloadItems(at: [self.mypath])
                }
            }

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UI updates like `cell.LBLLikesDetail.text =` should be done in main thread. I'm not sure that the completion of `postWithURL()` is done in main thread. But the main issue is that you shouldn't call `dequeueReusableCell` other that in `tableView(_:cellForRow:)`, that's not the cell that you think it is.

Comment: Not related to the issue: Name your var starting with a lowercase: `CollecDetail` => `collecDetail`, etc. Avoid using NSStuff in Swift3+, prefers Swift equivalents: `NSDictionary` => `Dictionary`, or better [String: Any] (if it fits your case). Also, avoid force unwrap (using the "!") prefers `if let`/`guard let`.

Comment: just update datasource and reload cell, thats it.

Comment: can you please check response is not equal to nil?

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the cell that **already exists** in the collectionView *instead* of **dequeue-ing another**. You need to use,

```
self.CollecDetail.cellForItem(at: self.myPath)
```

instead of,

```
self.CollecDetail.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: self.mypath)
```

Also, the **UI** operations should be done on the **main thread**. So, wrap every UI operation in the completion block inside the main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //UI Changes
}
```

---

**Note:** Swift naming conventions state that variable names should be *lowerCamelCase*. Also, as pointed out by @Larme in the comments, use of Swift types is recommended and force unwrapping should be avoided if there is a possibility that for the variable to be `nil`.